# backbone.js why is el undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

why do I get the error el is underfined -- thanks

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript">
    var SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        id: 'todo-id',
        className: 'todo-class',
        render: function() {
            var htmls = '<h3>jhjljlkjkljkljkljkljkjkjj</h3>';
            //this.$el.html(htmls);
            $(this.el).html(htmls);
        }



    });
    var simpleView = new SimpleView();
    simpleView.render();
    //console.log(simpleView.el);



    </script>
```

Comment: In your `render` method, put a `console.log(this)` and post the results.

Comment: Shrug.  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/GYGF7/

Oh... um, you're pointing to an ancient version of backbone.

Comment: You should accept @EdwardMSmith answer.  It is definately the best solution.  You may be able to tweak your code to get it to work but upgrading is definately the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works.

http://jsfiddle.net/GYGF7/

```
var SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    id: 'todo-id',
    className: 'todo-class',
    render: function() {
        var htmls = '<h3>jhjljlkjkljkljkljkljkjkjj</h3>';
        //this.$el.html(htmls);
        $(this.el).html(htmls);
    }



});
var simpleView = new SimpleView();
simpleView.render();
console.log(simpleView.el);
```

Your issue is that you're pointing to a very old version of backbone (0.3.3).

Update your dependency links to load the most recent version.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define what `el` is:

```
   var SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("YourElement"),
        tagName: 'li',
        id: 'todo-id',
        className: 'todo-class',
        render: function() {
            var htmls = '<h3>jhjljlkjkljkljkljkljkjkjj</h3>';
            //this.$el.html(htmls);
            $(this.el).html(htmls);
        }
    });
```

**Edit**

It looks like I might be wrong:

> if specified. If not, el is an empty div. (from http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)